# Sorting PivotTable With Export-Excel In PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

Using the Export-Excel command, I can successfully create the pivottable:

```
$Results `
    |Export-Excel -Path $sFilePath `
                    -WorksheetName "RAW Results" `
                    -TableName "tblResults" `
                    -PivotTableName "pvtResults" `
                    -BoldTopRow -ErrorAction Stop `
                    -PivotData  @{"IP"="Count"} 
                    -TableStyle Dark4 `
                    -AutoSize -Show
```

The pivottable is created with the counts however the counts in the pivot table are not sorted and the resultant chart is not either. I still have to manually sort the pivottable.

Is there a way to use the Export-Excel to sort the pivottable Count column in descending order?

Comment: What if you sort the `$Results` object array before sending to Excel-Export? `$Results | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Export-Excel ..`

Comment: That will sort out the worksheet, however the pivottable performs aggregations that are unsorted.